# Is it possible to specify Kafka Stream topology starting sequence

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Let say I have Topology A that streams from Source A to Stream A, and I have Topology B which stream from Source B to stream B (used as Table B).

Then I have a stream/table join that joins Stream A and Table B.

As expected the join only triggers when something arrives in Stream A and theres a correlating record in Table B.

I have an architecture, where the source topics are still populated while the Kafka Stream is DEAD.  And messages are always arrives in source B before source A.

I am finding that when I restart Kafka Stream (by redeploy the app), the topology that streams stuff to stream A, can happen BEFORE the topology that streams stuff to Table B.

And as a result, the join won't trigger.

I know this is probably the expected behaviour, there's no coordination between separate topologies.

I was wondering if there is a mechanism, a delay or something that can ORDER/Sequence the start of the topologies?

Once they are up, they are fine, as I can ensure the message arrives in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to try setting the [max.task.idle.ms](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.3.2/constant-values.html#org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.MAX_TASK_IDLE_MS_DOC) to something greater than the default (0), maybe 30 secs? It's tough to give a precise answer, so you'll have to experiment some.

HTH,
Bill

Answer (score 0):

If you need to trigger a downstream result from both sides of the join, you have to do a KTable-to-KTable join. From the [javadoc](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KTable.html#leftJoin-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KTable-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueJoiner-):

"The join is computed by (1) updating the internal state of one KTable and (2) performing a lookup for a matching record in the current (i.e., processing time) internal state of the other KTable. This happens in a symmetric way, i.e., for each update of either this or the other input KTable the result gets updated."

EDIT: Even if you do stream-to-KTable join that triggers only when a new stream event is emitted on the left side of the join (KTable updates do not emit downstream event), when you start the topology Streams will try to do timestamp re-synchronisation using the timestamps of the input events, and there should not be any race condition between the rate of consumption of the KTable source and the stream topic. BUT, my understanding is that this is on a best effort cases. E.g. if two events have exactly the same timestamp then Streams cannot deduce which should be processed first.

Comment: Thanks. However, that is windowed. Is it possible to have this non windowed ? Or a 2 week long window…

Comment: KTable-to-KTable join does not have to be windowed. Actually by default there is no window or TTL for the KTable key-value entries. They stay there forever and actually you should take care to delete them if you foresee that you might run out of disk space, e.g. if you are using a RocksDB option.

Comment: See here: https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/schedule-ktable-ttl/kstreams.html

Comment: cheers! If that works for u pls mark the answer as the correct one for future visitors..